# Python uppercase the entire string except letters which are within quotes but after colon

Tags: python, regex, string

I have string in python like

```
INS_hdr:"To:abc.micky.com|From:xyz.micky.com",TRANSFERTARGET:"B_london"
```

need to convert to like this

```
INS_HDR:"TO:abc.micky.com|FROM:xyz.micky.com",TRANSFERTARGET:"B_LONDON"
```

I dont want to convert string to uppercase based on colon, as i use multiple colon in string, need to convert uppercase based on colon which appear inside quotes

Comment: Please add more details on what the replacement logic here.  I don't see a very clear rule above.

Answer (score 1):

I would just brute force it, iterating and keeping track of the state
(in quote, in quote after colon, not in quote).

Any solution must treat : differently if : is in a quote or not.  I cannot see how to do this with regular expressions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Given your particular example, you could `re.split` on `:` with a non quoted word, then loop over the groups to determine which ones to make upper case based on the leading colon:

```
import re

s = 'INS_hdr:"To:abc.micky.com|From:xyz.micky.com",TRANSFERTARGET:"B_london"'

''.join(x.upper() if not x.startswith(':') else x 
        for x in re.split('(:[^"|]+)', s))
```

output:

```
INS_HDR:"TO:abc.micky.com|FROM:xyz.micky.com",TRANSFERTARGET:"B_LONDON"
```